# Can't read input from a pin in Arduino ATmega2560

Tags: c, arduino, microcontroller, avr

I'm tying to read the data from a HC-S501 PIR motion sensor connected to pin 7 of an Arduino ATmega2560. The code I'm using is:

```c
int main(void)
{
    int pir_out;

    pir_out = 0;
    DDRH &= ~(1 << PORTH4);
    DDRB |= 1 << PORTB7;
    PORTH &= ~(1 << PORTH4);
    PORTB &= ~(1 << PORTB7);
    while (1)
    {
        pir_out = PIND & (1 << PIND7);
        if (pir_out)
            PORTB |= 1 << PORTB7;
        else
            PORTB &= ~(1 << PORTB7);
    }
}
```

As you can see in the code, the LED on the arduino should turn on when the sensor detects something, but when I compile and upload this to the board, nothing happens. I tried to figure out what was going on and I'm very sure that I messed up something when trying to read the pin.

Comment: What's on pin 4? You seem to initialise it, but then you read from pin 7 and then WRITE to pin 7. Is the LED on pin 4? Or something like that - I've never used an Arduino.

Comment: `PIND & (1 << PIND7)` does not seem to be correct.

Comment: @hcheung I think it IS correct, PIND7 expands to just 7, so when the input is high the value will be 0x80 (nonzero = true) and 0x00 (false) if the input is low.

Comment: @anton-tchekov, that's not what I means, maybe I should elaborate a little bit more, OP set PH4 as input (which is Arduino D7), and PB7 as output (which is Arduino D13), and PB7 happened to be where the LED is connected on ATmega2560 Arduino Board, so `PIND & (1 << PIND7)` should really should be `PINH & (1 << PINH4)` which is where the PIR motion sensor is connected to at PH4(D7). Beside, `PIND & (1 << PIND7)` is checking status for Port D, Pin7 which has nothing connected to.